# IOS/React-native Twilio IP Messaging Shutdown

Tags: ios, react-native, twilio, twilio-api

I'm building an app using the Twilio IP Messaging SDK for iOS (actually using react-native, but have a bridge that uses Obj-C for the Twilio library). The app has the concept of "accounts", so once someone logs out I shut down the Twilio IP Messaging Client by calling the `shutdown()` method. This seems to work and I get the following output (not showing all, just the end):

https://gist.github.com/Baisang/1bb975c353772bb99a95fbcf4a4df87a

This seems to indicate a successful shutdown. However, when I log back in (which restarts the client by creating a new one?), I start getting a lot of poco exceptions and invalid socket errors.

https://gist.github.com/Baisang/a73fdc2f20db9a5ce1f0935cfb862e45

This continues and the client is never able to truly connect to Twilio as a result. Would like some insight into what may be causing this issue. For reference, the Twilio code I am using is here: https://github.com/ccm-innovation/react-native-twilio-ip-messaging/blob/master/RCTTwilioIPMessaging/RCTTwilioIPMessagingClient.m

Comment: @biasang is this still an issue for you? If you open an issue on the repo I'm more likely to see it to help assist. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever end up getting this to work? I am having trouble adding this module to my project, would you mind helping me out?

Comment: I'm no longer working on the app, but we decided to just not call shutdown() at all. It seems to be more of an issue with the SDK rather than Brad's Twilio Bridge.

Comment: @FreddieCabrera thanks for checking out the project.. if you have any issues please post there as I don't see these questions.